# An AutoHotkey script hotkey to text

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I want to write a script so when I press Control key and 5 for example the system type certain sentence -have a good day - for example .. please help!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AutoHotkey! If you haven't already, I recommend reading the documentation for [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm). For your request, one way to write that code would be as follows:

```
^5::
   Send,Hello world
return
```

That will simulate typing the message. If you want it to appear *almost* instantly, you can use this:

```
^5::
   SendInput,Hello world
return
```